# Finding matching character strings in 2 sets of data in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have 2 data sets; one contains information on patients, and the other is a list of medical codes

```
patient <- data.table(ID = rep(1:5, each = 3),
                  codes = c("13H42", "1B1U", "Eu410", "Je450", "Fg65", "Eu411", "Eu402", "B110", "Eu410", "Eu50",
                           "1B1U", "Eu513", "Eu531", "Eu411", "Eu608")
                                        )
code <- data.table(codes = c("BG689", "13H42", "BG689", "Ju34K", "Eu402", "Eu410", "Eu50", "JE541", "1B1U", 
                        "Eu411", "Fg605", "GT6TU"), 
               term = c(NA))
```

The `code$term` has values, but for this example they're omitted.

What I want is an indicator column in `patient` that shows 1 if a code in `code` occurs in `patient$codes`.

```
 patient
    ID codes    mh
 1:  1 13H42  TRUE
 2:  1  1B1U  TRUE
 3:  1 Eu410  TRUE
 4:  2 Je450 FALSE
 5:  2  Fg65 FALSE
 6:  2 Eu411  TRUE
 7:  3 Eu402  TRUE
 8:  3  B110 FALSE
 9:  3 Eu410  TRUE
10:  4  Eu50  TRUE
11:  4  1B1U  TRUE
12:  4 Eu513 FALSE
13:  5 Eu531 FALSE
14:  5 Eu411  TRUE
15:  5 Eu608 FALSE
```

My solution was to use grepl:

```
patient$mh <- mapply(grepl, pattern=code$codes, x=patient$codes)
```

however this didn't work as `code` isn't the same length and i got the warning

```
Warning message:
In mapply(grepl, pattern = code$codes, x = patient$codes) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

Any solutions for an exact match?

Comment: Do you want exact match?

Comment: Are you sure your expected output is correct? Think you can just do `patient$mh <- patient$codes %in% code$codes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
patient[,mh := codes %in% code$codes]
```

**Update:**

As rightly suggested by [Pasqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4023136/pasqui), for getting 0s and 1s,

you can further do:

```
patient[,mh := as.numeric(mh)]
```

Comment: and then `patient[,mh := as.numeric(mh)]` because he wants 0s and 1s :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: others have posted better answers. I like the %in% one from @moto myself. Much more concise, and much more efficient. Stick with those :)

This should do it. I've used a for loop, so you might figure something out that would be more efficient. I've also split the loop up into a few lines, rather than squeezing it into one. That's just so you can see what's happening:

```
for( row in 1:nrow(patient) ) {
    codecheck <- patient$codes[row]
    output <- ifelse( sum( grepl( codecheck, code$codes ) ) > 0L, 1, 0 )
    patient$new[row] <- output
}
```

So this just goes through the patient list one by one, checks for a match using grepl, then puts the result (1 for match, 0 for no match) back into the patient frame, as a new column.

Is that what you're after?